# Automatically making a path to the users directory

Tags: files-and-directories

I am trying to set the code to regardless of user, it will set the Directory of that user to the desktop. I have tried to use the SetDirectory[] and add that string to another, however the hidden "" makes that part of the code useless. How can I make a code that sets the Directory to the person that uses the codes Desktop without manually changing the user name within the code?

Comment: What OS are you considering? Do you want e.g. something that's Windows only, or should it also work for Macs and Linux?

Comment: Windows only - But if you have the solution for both i welcome them as well.

Comment: Then `FileNameJoin[{$HomeDirectory, "Desktop"}]` should suffice for Windows?

Comment: It  works! Many thanks.